# android bluetoothadapter.startLeScan, filter by UUID

Tags: java, uuid

I want to scan BLE device with the `startLeScan(UUID[] serviceUuids, LeScanCallback callback)` method, now I have a UUID, it's a 16-bits value, for example, `00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB`.

How can I use the UUID in `startLeScan` method, I write like this,

```
UUID[] uuid = new UUID[1]; uuid[0] = UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(uuid, mLeScanCallback);
```

But finally I can scan nothing. How can I resolve this problem.

Comment: were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: Same here. Not getting any results after the scan. Have you made any progress?

Comment: Actually your code works for me. Are you sure that your UUID is the one of a advertised service?

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem. Did you get any solution for this ? or any work around ?

Answer (score 2):

I used the same method as you，and i added permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file like below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

hope that will help you.