# startLeScan not returning any results when filtering

Tags: android, filtering, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to scan for a specific BLE advertisement based on UUID.
I came up with the below code but the scan does not return any result.

```
final UUID[] comm_UUID = {UUID.fromString("0000b81d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")};
mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(comm_UUID, mLeScanCallback);
```

I tried scanning without the filter `mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);` and it is working just fine, but callback reports all BLE advertisements in the vicinity.

Am I performing the scan incorrectly?

Comment: So when you scan without filtering, can you see device with that UUID - `0000b81d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` ?

Comment: Yes! I can also see all the nearby low energy devices due to the absence of filter(which is not desired).

Comment: Are you sure that you see device with that UUID? Did you check it with debugger?

Comment: Yes i'm sure. I checked it in debugger and printed the list of devices on screen as well.

Comment: a similar problem un-answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256110/android-bluetoothadapter-startlescan-filter-by-uuid

Comment: cant it be your case - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18899320/632516 ?